# Passing refs from Parent(functional component) down to child(class component) and then down to another child(functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const Container = props => {
  const ref = React.createRef()
  return (
   <div> 
   {props.flag ? < Search reference={ref}/> : <Dropdown / > } 
   </div>
  )
}

class Search extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.reference)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <JButton btnRef={this.props.reference}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const JButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={props.btnRef}>
        Hello
      </button>
    </div>
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to create a ref and pass it down a couple children.

I've created the ref using `React.createRef()`, in my top parent component, and implemented it there to see if it worked (and it did).

Now I'm trying to pass it down to the child (class component) and then pass it down to its child (functional component).

Right now I'm passing the ref as a prop from the top parent component to the child, but it keeps coming up as undefined when I try `console.log` the ref on a `componentDidMount()`.

Once I can successfully pass it down, I will pass it down one more level (which is going from a class component to a functional component).

I know I need to use `React.forwardRef()` in my functional component to receive refs.

Im using ref`s to modify the focus after clicking on different elements on the page.

Below is a very simple code snippet of what I'm trying to do. The snippet starts off at the top with a functional component that creates the ref with React.createRef(). Then it gets passed down the the Search component which is a class component. When I call console.log this.props.reference it comes back as null. Eventually, I would like this ref passed all the way down to the Jbutton component.

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Please note that the example should be **minimal**, but should demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The code you provided seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-moon-pt9sp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: looks everything is working now which is pretty weird.

Comment: yep it works for me can you say your React version?

Comment: 16.6.3. Working for me now as well. @VictorCastro